# Пишу парсер с авито на python, помогите правильно составить запрос

Tags: python, парсер

Пишу код парсинга данных об автомобилях с авито.
Вот ссылка для примера:

*https://www.avito.ru/tobolsk/avtomobili/toyota_camry_2010_1343073375*

```
import requests, bs4
s=requests.get('https://www.avito.ru/tobolsk/avtomobili/toyota_camry_2010_1343073375')
b=bs4.BeautifulSoup(s.text, "html.parser")
p3=b.select('.item-params-list .item-params-label')
f1=p3[0].getText ()
```

В ответ получаю:

> 'Коробка передач: '

Как мне получить результат этой строки, т.е. автомат или механика?

И ещё вопрос, как мне одновременно спарсить все колонки, потому что у них у всех код `item-params-label`?

Comment: Выбрать все `.item-params-list-item`, обойти их в цикле, на каждой итерации получая из текущего элемента текст и дочерний элемент с классом `item-params-label`.

Comment: Все равно не получается текст-значение  получить, можете написать как это делается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если привязывать к структуре

```
for item in b.select('.item-params-list-item'):
    value = item.contents[2].strip()
    label = item.find('span').text
    print(label, value)
```

Если не привязываться

```
value = ''.join(item.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip()
```

Наверняка можно и проще.

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажите еще как в первую строку вывести цену?

Comment: @Max [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: `price = b.select_one('.js-item-price')`

Comment: В таком случае мне выдается:
   
 `<span class="js-item-price" content="720000" itemprop="price">720 000</span>`
А мне нужно только само значение

Comment: @Max я был уверен, что вы догадаетесь использовать `price.text`.

Comment: Я получил значение через `value = price.contents[0].strip()` , какую из двух команд лучше использовать?

Comment: В этом теге кроме текста ничего нет, так что обращаться к `contents` явно избыточно.